# Normality of subgroups isn’t transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I’m trying to disprove the following statement: “let $G$ be a group, and suppose $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$; if $H$ is normal in $G$ and $K$ is normal in $H$, then $K$ is normal in $G$.”

My counterexample is with $G=D_4$, $H=\{e,a^2,b,a^2b\}$, and $K=\{e,b\}$.

I know that $H$ is normal in $G$ because $[G:H]=2$ and I know that $K$ is normal in $H$ because $[H:K]=2$. But we have that $[G:K]=4$, with $b \notin Z(G)$. So, $K$ is not normal in $G$.  Therefore, normality of subgroups is not transitive. Is this correct?

Comment: That's right, and this is one of the standard examples.

Comment: Another one is given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752021/normality-is-not-transitive). There are several more posts about it, e.g., see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255274/are-normal-subgroups-transitive).